# Facebook offline conversions without customer data associating with ad reporting

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I have ads on Facebook driving traffic to our site.
I set this on land

```
fbq('init', 'my_id', {
  external_id: "d1fd01cb777cdcdbf5161db889bf841e"
})
```

and later if we have an actual purchase I send an offline purchase event using extern_id to match on.

```
[{
  :match_keys => {
    :extern_id => "d1fd01cb777cdcdbf5161db889bf841e"
  },
  :event_time => 1579464000,
  :event_name => "Purchase",
  :value => 5.0,
  :currency => "USD",
  :order_id => "8431715",
  :custom_data => {
    :event_source => "affiliate"
  }
}]
```

however I am not seeing the offline events associated with the ads.

Has anyone else had this issue and have they found a solution??

Answer (score 0):

Davinj, if I understood you correctly, you try to send pixel events giving your `extren_id` and then matching it back to customers who made a purchase as offline conversions? I see several issue with this:

1. You have your `extern_id` in pixel's init code instead of event itself. Like standard conversions or at least page view. Also you call it `extrn[al]_id` which is inconsistent with `extern_id`.
2. I doubt that such scenario would work in the first place as offline conversions do not usually play well with pixel and might not be able to have the parameter from pixel as a `match key`. Even if the do, which you might find via testing, you'll still have to send other match keys to identify the FB user like `email`, `phone number`, etc. Here are docs explicitly recommending that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/offline-conversions#extern-id
3. When you have a consistent pixel setup and can see proper events with corresponding parameters, you'll be able to see if you idea is viable.
4. Generally FB explicitly says that `extern_id` is a user identifier in you system and probably has to be different for every customer. It can be send as a lonely match key only after you already used it once with other match cases to identify an FB user. Otherwise FB just skips such events and you'll see nothing.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was going off their documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/advanced/advanced-matching it says use external_id for pixel and extern_id for offline

Comment: Happy hacking then

Answer (score 0):

@Davinj, 
There is another way to send offline events via server-side-api to your pixel's dataset:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/server-side-api

I think these should match up as they show in the same pixel when using event manager.

I had the same assumptions as you but I think their offline conversions is for people who didn't land on your site before converting. Maybe just saw your advert or something.

Comment: thanks, i have tried that as well and I get this error. {"error":{"message":"(#3) This pixel is not enabled for this capability: SERVER_SIDE_EVENTS_CORE_FUNCTIONALITY","type":"OAuthException","code":3,"fbtrace_id":"AvpoiI5IdfzAa3YFXWyx2sM"}}%   . the ability to set server side api for web isn't available in my pixel settings.

Comment: @Davinj, Yes I'm also in the process of discussing with facebook support about enabling my pixel for server side API. So I get the same message as you.

Comment: @Davinj, Try now .... server-side API got enabled after a month. Might be a time activated feature after monitoring