# Facebook Server-Side API (Marketing API)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-pixel

First of all - sorry for my english, not my primary language.

We are trying to send some Pixel events from server (not from user browser), so we have an instructions from facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/server-side-api
But stuck on step "Create Access Token", this section (Server-Side API for Web) is missing in Pixel's settings.

Also when we trying to make request to graph api to send some events we getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) This pixel is not enabled for this capability: SERVER_SIDE_EVENTS_CORE_FUNCTIONALITY",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3,
    "fbtrace_id": "AEWB5WGs0g_e21p2Qd1kZsX"
  }
}
```

Is anyone managed to resolve this issue?

Comment: You'll need to request access from Facebook. I've had no luck finding out how as an app review is only for the access token part of it:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59848233/facebook-offline-conversions-without-customer-data-associating-with-ad-reporting/60099399#60099399

Answer (score 0):

Mindesik,

At least before you had to be whitelisted (approved by FB) to be able to use server-side API from FB. It's usually not explicitly mentioned on the FB dev portal. If you have an FB representative for your business, try to ask them. Looking at the docs it looks quite promising, so the things might have changed.

Still, in case you've followed all the steps correctly and still getting this error this is most probably whitelisting issue that is implicitly required. The problem here is that to make FB aware of users associated with the events you send you have to send Personally identifiable information (PII) which would be a subject of strict compliance according to local laws in the EU and the US.
Here is what is says to me about debugging S2S events:

[image]